# Spectator: override provider for single test (angular universal)

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-unit-test, spectator

I built a small angular app and now I'm writing unit tests. So far so good, but when I try to test my authGuard I ran into some problems. I am using [Spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator).
I provide the platformId in the providers section in my spec, but I want to be able to overwrite it so I can test scenarios where for values 'server' as well as 'browser'
My code is for the authGuard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): boolean | UrlTree | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      console.log('server');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('browser');
      this.authService.autoLogin();
      return this.authService.user.pipe(
        take(1),
        map((user) => {
          console.log('user', user);
          if (!!user) {
            return true;
          }
          console.log('navugate');
          this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
          return false;
        }),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And the spec file:

```
describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorService<AuthGuard>;
  const config = {
    service: AuthGuard,
    imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [AppRoutingModule, AuthService, { provide: PLATFORM_ID, useValue: 'server' }],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  };
  const createService = createServiceFactory(config);

// some other tests here ....

  it('should should navigate to /auth if running on browser and not authenticated', () => {
    config.providers = [AppRoutingModule, { provide: PLATFORM_ID, useValue: 'browser' }];
    spectator = createService();
    const spyNavigate = spyOn(spectator.service['router'], 'navigate').and.callThrough();
    const user = new User('bla@bla.com', 'id', 'token', new Date(10000));
    spectator.service['authService'].user.next(user);
    spectator.service.canActivate(null, null);
    expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Now when I run this overriding the config does not work. This is to be expected, since the config object was already passed on before altering it.
But how to achieve my goal?
I tried this:

```
describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorService<AuthGuard>;
  const config = {
    service: AuthGuard,
    imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [AppRoutingModule, AuthService, { provide: PLATFORM_ID, useValue: 'server' }],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  };

// some other tests here ....

  it('should should navigate to /auth if running on browser and not authenticated', () => {
    config.providers = [AppRoutingModule, { provide: PLATFORM_ID, useValue: 'browser' }];
    const createService = createServiceFactory(config);
    spectator = createService();
    const spyNavigate = spyOn(spectator.service['router'], 'navigate').and.callThrough();
    const user = new User('bla@bla.com', 'id', 'token', new Date(10000));
    spectator.service['authService'].user.next(user);
    spectator.service.canActivate(null, null);
    expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But that gave me the error `Error: 'beforeEach' should only be used in 'describe' function` which I found confusing since I am not using beforeEach in this spec.

I feel that some tool like Spectator should probably have an easy way to do this, it is not that exotic, right?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing arguments to `createService()`:

```js
createService({
  providers: [...]
});
```

Comment: gives an error : `Cannot override provider when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `overrideProvider`. `